# ArcGIS Online Map using URL does not work with PhoneGap

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, android, arcgis-online, arcgis-android, phonegap

I wanted to show my public accessible ArcGIS Online map with URL on a simple Hello World PhoneGap project with Eclipse. Eclipse threw out the following error in LogCat.

Web Console:RequestError: Unable to load file: //www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/{MapId}?f=json status: 0 at http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/js...3.4compact/:15

Just wondering anyone have had any successful experience with using ArcGIS Online web map with PhoneGap?

Comment: Try this http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.4compact/

Comment: Thanks Sunil for your quick response. However, the Html file was using exactly the same ArcGIS JS api as you pointed out: <script src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.4compact/"></script>. For some reason, stackexchange omitted out "http".

Comment: check out this sample http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jssamples/mobile_findnearby.html

Comment: I gave the samples there a go. Found the live sample worked well; but when downloaded and unzipped it to local and ran the sample locally, it threw out the same error on Chrome. "Unable to load the file... ..." Could be an Ajax issue? As it runs on Android, there will be no proxy file. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/839...h-PhoneGap-2.7

esri.arcgis.utils.arcgisUrl = esri.arcgis.utils.arcgisUrl.replace("file:", "http:");

Comment: Your link seems to be to a different thread from the one that you intended.